# Cannot get the input value from Java GUI Textfield

Tags: java

I study in computer programming and i am trying to simulate an ATM machine. I have some problem on the textfeild with the name inputArea. Here is some of my Code

Here is the constructor of the GUI

```
public ATM() {
  inputArea = new JTextField();
  inputArea.setText("");
  inputArea.setEditable(true);
  add( inputArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  TextFieldHandler handler = new TextFieldHandler();
  inputArea.addActionListener(handler);
}
```

This is the event handler

```
 private class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
       if(event.getSource()==inputArea) {
           inputMessage = event.getActionCommand();
           inputArea.setText("");
       }
   }
 }
```

When the program start, it will crash. How can i make it stop and wait until the i input the value into the text field then press enter. So the accountNumber can become the value i input.

```
private void authenticateUser()
{
  displayMessage( "\nPlease enter your account number: " );
  int accountNumber = Integer.parseInt(inputMessage);
  displayMessage( "\nEnter your PIN: " ); // prompt for PIN
  int pin = Integer.parseInt(inputMessage);
}
```

Here is the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
  at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
  at ATM.authenticateUser(ATM.java:118)
  at ATM.run(ATM.java:94)
  at ATMCaseStudy.main(ATMCaseStudy.java:14)
```

Feel free to let me know if there is any suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How is displayMessage implemented?

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of `inputMessage` before parsing it? That exception isn't just random text - it is there to help!

Comment: I think the problem is that displayMessage doesn't wait for the user to complete the input. Therefore inputMessage is empty. Checking for an empty message there would avoid the Exception but it doesn't help with the actual cause.

Comment: @No3x the displayMessage is implemented with this                                  
  `static void displayMessage(String message) {
    show=message;
    screenMessage=screenMessage.concat(show);
    ATMScreen.setText(screenMessage);
   }`

Comment: @John3136 The program can not do with the Text Field Handler so i can not input any value to it

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with parsing "" to Integer.
I don't work with Swing, but I have a few idea to fix it:
1) Try change default value, `inputArea.setText("0");`
2) Try valid input
3) Use debbuger to check what value you have in "inputMessage" -If u don't never use it, please check it, is very usefulin the future

Comment: Thank you for your ideas and i tried them but it still do not work well. I tried to use the debuger but it seem that the program can not get the input from the GUI panel and crash on `int accountNumber = Integer.parseInt(inputMessage)`

Comment: Try replace  inputMessage = event.getActionCommand(); With inputMessage  = inputArea.getText(); It look like you want to get comand type, but you realy want value from JTextArea

Comment: it cause the same result with the previous one. Maybe i try to change the order of the program code to see. Is there are any changes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a combination of a command line program and a GUI program.

Get rid of the command line functionality.

You could either:

1. Display a JOptionPane to prompt the user for the information you require. You would need two option panes, one to prompt for the account number and one for the pin. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and working example.
2. Create a custom JDialog. A JDialog is just like a JFrame, you add components to the dialog. So you would add a label and a text field for the account number and then a second set of label and formatted text field for the pin. Then you need to add a button to close the dialog and read the data from the text fields so you can do your processing.

Look at the section from the above tutorial on `How to Use Password Fields` and `How to Use Buttons` for more information and simple working examples to get you more experienced with using a GUI.

Comment: Please note the ``modal`` property in the mentioned docs. It reflects my assumption about the issue with your code. If you still want to read the values the console you can archive similar behaviour - please let us know.